# perl DBI and placeholders

Tags: perl, dbi

I have this query `select * from table where ID in (1,2,3,5...)`

How is it possible to build this query with the DBI using placeholders ?

for example :

```
my @list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my $sql = "select * from table where ID in (?)";

$sth->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

What argument should I send to execute? Is it a list or a string separated by `,` or something else?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should build your query dynamically according to the number of items in your array

```
my @list =(1,2,3,4,5);
my $sql ="select * from table where ID in (@{[join',', ('?') x @list]})";
```

Answer (score 13):

It's not possible in that way. You need to specify a placeholder for each item in your array:

```
my @list = (1,2,3,4,5);
my $sql = "select * from table where ID in (?,?,?,?,?)";

$sth->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(@list);
```

If your `@list` is not a fixed size, you need to build the `$sql` with the proper number of placeholders.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [`DBI` documentation](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI):

> Also, placeholders can only represent single scalar values.  For example, the following statement won't work as expected
>          for more than one value:
>
> ```
>      SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE name IN (?)    # wrong
>      SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE name IN (?,?)  # two names
> ```

Rewrite to:

```
my $sql = 'select * from table where ID in ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )';
$sth->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(@list);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using DBI to access a PostgreSQL database with the DBD::Pg driver, you can use:

```
my @list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my $sql = "select * from table where ID = ANY(?::INT[]);";

$sth->prepare ($sql);
$sth->execute (\@list);
```

Comment: I don't think you even need the `::INT[]`. Just `id = ANY(?)` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the exact number of elements you cannot use placeholders. Try this:

```
my @list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);  # any number of elements
my $in = join(',', map { $dbh->quote($_) } @list);
my $sql = "select * from table where someid IN ($in)";
```

Comment: As you can see from other answers, it is possible to use placeholders since it is easy to find out the size of an array, even though it comes from a dynamic source...

Comment: Using placeholders for lists makes sense if you prepare the statement once and then execute it multiple times with the exact same number of arguments; in this case it will only be overhead and increase the likeliness to exceed maximum query size.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to [DBIx::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aSimple) you can just say:

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (??)', $foo, $bar, $baz);
```

?? Means "as many as needed"

**Edit:**

Actually, I was a little too optimistic: *"If the string (??) is present in the query, it is replaced with a list of as many question marks as @values."*

So this does not seem to work:

```
$db->query( "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (??) AND stuff=?", @ids, $stuff )
```

Still useful though..

For the curious, the code in the module is:

```
# Replace (??) with (?, ?, ?, ...)
sub _replace_omniholder {
  my ($self, $query, $binds) = @_;
  return if $$query !~ /\(\?\?\)/;
  my $omniholders = 0;
  my $q = $self->{dbd} =~ /mysql/ ? $quoted_mysql : $quoted;
  $$query =~ s[($q|\(\?\?\))] {
    $1 eq '(??)'
    ? do {
        Carp::croak('There can be only one omniholder')
            if $omniholders++;
        '(' . join(', ', ('?') x @$binds) . ')'
    }
    : $1
  }eg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a sure way for this to work summarizing all of the above advice. My Production query (I posted a much simpler version here) uses IN <>, where neither the codes nor their quantity is unknown. It could be a single Code (e.g. `FIN`), or a series of them (`FITLC FITLD FITLU FITSC FITSD FITSU MDYLC MDYLD MDYLU`). Some function returns that as a list.

The code that makes this happen is

```
            @codes =  get_muni_evcode( $category );
            my $in = join( ', ', ('?') x @codes );
            print "\n\nProcessing Category: $category --> Codes: @codes   .. in: $in\n";

            my $sql = "select distinct cusip9 
            from material_event 
            where event_date between (trunc(sysdate) - 1) + 2/3 and trunc(sysdate) + 2/3 
            and event_code in ($in)";
            my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth2->execute( @codes );

            while (my $s2 = $sth2->fetchrow_hashref('NAME_lc'))
            {
                    my $cusip9 = $s2->{cusip9};
                    print "$cusip9\t";
                   .................. further processing ..............

            }
```

The result sample:

`Processing Category: RatingChange --> Codes: FITLC FITLD FITLU FITSC FITSD FITSU MDYLC MDYLD MDYLU MDYSC MDYSD MDYSU SPLD SPLPR SPLU SPSD SPSPR SPSU   .. in: ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
359496HQ2       359496GB6       359496GH3       359496GL4       359496HU3       359496HS8       359496HA7       359496HF6       359496GM2       359496HM1       359496HR0       359496HT6   359496GY6        359496GJ9       359496HL3       359496GU4       359496HK5       359496HN9       359496HP4       359496GW0       359496GZ3       359496HC3       359496GC4       359496GK6   359496GP5        359496GV2       359496GX8       359496GN0`

I'm extremely grateful to everybody who posted their ideas here that finally made me find the right way to do this. It must be a pretty common problem I think.